# Run serial jobs depending on maximum number of jobs using srun in slurm

Tags: parallel-processing, slurm, serial-processing

Good day,
Is there a way to set slurm that when the number of jobs exceed the maximum number of jobs a user have the rest will be performed serially automatically?

For example; I have a maximum of 50 jobs that I can run at the same time.
I want to send 200 jobs, meaning that I will have 50 jobs at a time, 4 times.

Please note that each job will be sent separately using srun (I am using a simulation program that can only use this option with slurm).

Thank you in advance.

I want a function that is similar to the task spooler option tsk -s N, but for the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you have access to configure the SLURM cluster** (i.e. you're not simply a user of the cluster), then you can accomplish what you want by configuring resource limits for SLURM (reference [link](https://slurm.schedmd.com/resource_limits.html)).

Check out the "MaxJobs" limit.

> ```
> MaxJobs 
>
> The total number of jobs able to run at any given time for the given association.
> If this limit is reached, new jobs will be queued
> but only allowed to run after existing jobs in the association
> complete.
> ```

You'll need to follow the configuration requirements as described in the link.
For example, from the SLURM [accounting](https://slurm.schedmd.com/accounting.html#limit-enforcement) reference:

> To enable any limit enforcement you must at least have
> AccountingStorageEnforce=limits in your slurm.conf. Otherwise, even if
> you have limits set, they will not be enforced.

**Assuming that you do not have access to configure the SLURM cluster** (i.e. you're simply a user of the cluster), then you could look into job arrays but that might not be compatible with your "simulation program".  From the [sbatch](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) man page:

> -a, --array=<indexes>
>
> ```
> ...
>  maximum number of simultaneously running tasks from the job array may
>  be specified using a "%" separator. For example "--array=0-15%4" will
>  limit the number of simultaneously running tasks from this job array
>  to 4.
> ```